# jQuery .css() doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a quiz and want to highlight the correct answer when people answered wrong, however it only work with with showing the red one.

```
self.wrongAnswer = function(elm) {

        startSound('wrongsound', false);
        $(elm).toggleClass('correct');
        $(elm).css('background', 'red');
        var correctanswer = this.questions[self.level() - 1].correct;
        $("correctanswer").css('background', 'green');
```

Comment: I think you `$("correctanswer").css('background', 'green');` should be `$(correctanswer).css('background', 'green');`

Comment: Try this `$(correctanswer).css('background', 'green');`

Comment: `css()` works absolutely fine when you use it correctly.

Comment: check my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

You are applying `.css()` in a wrong way in jQuery `$("")` selector is used for selecting a `html` tag and here you are applying `jQuery` to a variable

So, change your `$("correctanswer").css('background', 'green');` to `$(correctanswer).css('background', 'green');`

Or may be

```
correctanswer.css('background', 'green');
```

//may be because I am answering from mobile phone and I am not sure and  can't check in mobile

Answer (score 0):

You should use the below code:

```
// If correctanswer is an 'id' it should be prefix with #
 $("#correctanswer").css('background', 'green');

// If correctanswer is class it should be prefix with .
 $(".correctanswer").css('background', 'green');
```

```js
$('#correctanswer').css('background','green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="correctanswer">
 this is correct answer
</div>
```